# c# DataGridview IndexOutOfRangeException (index X doesnt have a value)

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, datagrid, datatable

I have a datagridview and a datatable as a datasource. Sometimes, **Even though I check the if the data exists**, it gives me error like index X does not have a value, from the DataError event. **I checked all similar questions** but nothing fixed my issue. After the code I will printed the DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs error object  that I received.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
Form1_load()
{
        dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(long));
        dt.Columns.Add("field1", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("field2", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("field3", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("field4", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("field5", typeof(string));

        dt.PrimaryKey = new[] { AliveTable.Columns["id"] };

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.DataError += DataGridView_DataError;

}

public void ListData()
{
   foreach(var item in data)
  {
      if(item.delete)
      { 
        var row = dt.Rows.Find(item.id); 
        if(row != null) { row.Delete();}
        continue;
      }

      InserOrUpdateData(item.id);
   }

}

  public void InserOrUpdateData(long id)
  {
     var data = dataFromDb;

        bool exist = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(row => id == row.Field<long>("id"));

        var item1 = data ["field1"] != null ? data ["field1"] : String.Empty;
        var item2 = data ["field2"] != null ? data ["field2"] : String.Empty;
        var item3 = data ["field3"] != null ? data ["field3"] : String.Empty;
        var item4 = data ["field4"] != null ? data ["field4"] : String.Empty;
        var item5 = data ["field5"] != null ? data ["field5"] : String.Empty;

        if (exist)
        {
            dt.Rows.Find(id)["field1"] = item1;
            dt.Rows.Find(id)["field2"] = item2;
            dt.Rows.Find(id)["field3"] = item3;
            dt.Rows.Find(id)["field4"] = item4;
            dt.Rows.Find(id)["field5"] = item5;

        }
        else
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(id, item1, item2, item3, item4, item5);

        }

  }
   private void DataGridView_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message.ToString());
    }
```

And The received Error object(As JSON). Note: The indexes change

```
{
 "Context": 2,
 "Exception": {
 "ClassName": "System.IndexOutOfRangeException",
 "Message": "Index 3 does not have a value.",
 "Data": null,
 "InnerException": null,
 "HelpURL": null,
 "StackTraceString": "   at        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.GetError(Int32 rowIndex)",
"RemoteStackTraceString": null,
"RemoteStackIndex": 0,
"ExceptionMethod": "8\nGetError\nSystem.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Windows.Forms.DataGridView+DataGridViewDataConnection\nSystem.String GetError(Int32)",
"HResult": -2146233080,
"Source": "System.Windows.Forms",
"WatsonBuckets": null
 },
"ThrowException": false,
"ColumnIndex": 5,
"RowIndex": 3,
"Cancel": false
 }
```

Comment: "ColumnIndex": -1, : This is not valid.. Point of exception I guess

Comment: It is not always -1, sometimes 5, sometimes 3. As I sad it changes.

Comment: What are your values when the error occurs? Sounds like it is caused by you removing rows from the databound collection after databinding. There are some known issues around that. Try just modifying the source data (datatable in this case) and then re-databinding